Joining and filling two curves creates stray point at (0,0,0) using geometry nodes
Joining and filling two curves creates stray point at (0,0,0) using geometry nodes
Here's an example I create two curves and Join them it looks fine at first.

But when I try and create faces between them an extra point at (0,0,0) is created.

The only way to get around it is to delete the "stray" point at (0,0,0) is this a bug or am I missing something?

See attached blend file


Smells like a fencepost error, but I can't see it.

Well, you have the answer already there: there is a vertex with index 20 which you have to delete. Why there is this vertex, see my answer.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks! I knew I could fix it I just wasn't sure why it was happening and what was causing it.

Your resampled curve has 20 control points, the grid has 30 (3 × 10) vertices:
Resampled curve:

Grid:

Which means you read the positions of the control points from index 0 to 19 and try to set the positions of the vertices with index 0 to 29. This results in vertices 20 to 29 having no position information so they are all at (0, 0, 0). You can see them all in the Spreadsheet if you disable the Merge by Distance node. Then you merge them by distance and since they are all in the same location, this leaves only one vertex at (0, 0, 0), index 20:

Solution: Make the grid the same number of vertices like the curve. Set the Vertices X to 2 instead of 3 and you have 20 vertices (2 × 10). The Merge by Distance is no longer necessary then, I just did not delete it before taking the screenshot:

To be more specific: your grid can have more than 20 vertices - the crucial part here is to have only 2 vertices on X because you have two curves. When you are controlling the number of resampled points and Y rows with the same integer, the curve will always have twice the amount of control points in the end. The grid will always have the Vertices X times amount of vertices.
A higher number of Y vertices is no problem, you will just get a higher resolution on the curved shapes (but they will not be smoothed or anything, it's just more vertices between left and right end). This is because the indices are ordered this way, the first half is for one spline, the second for the other - and on the grid it is the same, one half is for one Y row of vertices, the other half for the other row. Making three rows in the grid messes everything up and results in a differing number of elements between curve and grid. By the way, mixing up X and Y on the grid (let's say 10 X vertices and 2 Y vertices) also messes up the result since the positions then always jump between curves.
Here an example with a grid with still only 2 vertices on X, but 32 on Y so it's 64 vertices altogether:


this answer is so detailed, but still missing link to off-by-one error https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

@Crantisz Feel free to edit it in. The thing is, the off-by-one error is only the final result because in the end he merges the "off-by-very-many" into a single vertex. The real issue here is that he set up the grid incorrectly. I edited my answer to make this more clear.
